# Special characters in FTP files

Tags: vb.net, ftp, special-characters, ftpwebrequest

I am facing problems to manage files in a FTP when they have special characters. For example filenames with `ó` or similars.

I give you an example. First I want to list and process each file of a folder in the FTP:

```
ftp = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(sFtpPath), FtpWebRequest)
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
reader = New StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())

files = reader.ReadToEnd.Split(New String() {NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
reader.Close()
```

But this is giving me problems when the file contains special characters because the string I have for the file doesn't "exists" on the FTP, for example:

```
For Each sFich As String In files
    ftp = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(sFtpPath & "/" & sFich), FtpWebRequest)
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    reader = New StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())

    '...
Next
```

For example, the file `EXAMPLE_aró` on the FTP, here is retrieved as `EXAMPLE_ar□`, so when I try to download the file it says that doesnt exist.

How can I deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369863/ftpwebrequest-filename-contains-german-umlaute-like-a-o), you may need to specify the encoding of the `StreamReader` you're using to get the file listing. The default is UTF8, you can use other encodings like so:

```
reader = New StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
```

When I run into encoding issues, I usually copy and paste the garbled string into an editor that can show the hex values for the characters, and then figure out the encoding from there.

The string you have above contains the character 00F3. Your profile says you are in Spain. Putting those two together, with the help of Google I am guessing the FTP server is using the Spanish flavor of EBCDIC, which is code page 1145. So try this:

```
reader = New StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1145))
```

Edit: Turns out F3 is the acute o in most encodings, including extended ASCII, the EBCDIC one just came up in my search.

Comment: Didn't work. Instead of having a list of filenames I get a single string in `reader.ReadToEnd` which I can't split and all the characters are invalid (all illegible squares). When opened in a proper editor, in unicode all are chinese characters, and with "1145" encoding all are strange characters like `ÃÁÊÈ/ëÍÂ`

Comment: Which `ASCII` it list the files but puts an `?` where the special characters should be.

Comment: Worked! With encoding `1252 Western European (Windows)` using `Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`. It reads the special characters!  Edit your answer for future people and I mark your answer. By the way, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.codepage.aspx) might be useful.

Comment: Or maybe [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.codepage.aspx), which has more encodings.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using some special characters and the below works well for me. The listDir function creates the list... Maybe you can try and let us know...

```
 Public Shared Function DownloadFileFromServer(fileUri As Uri) As Boolean

    If fileUri.Scheme <> Uri.UriSchemeFtp Then
        Return False
    End If
    ' Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    Dim request As New WebClient()


    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
    Try
        Dim newFileData As Byte() = request.DownloadData(fileUri.ToString())
        Dim fileString As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData)
        'do something with data
        Console.WriteLine(fileString)
    Catch e As WebException
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
    End Try
    Return True
End Function

Public Shared Function listDir() As Boolean

    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.yourftpsite.com/docs/"), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")

    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

    Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)

    Dim dirlist As String() = Nothing
    dirlist = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(New String() {vbCr & vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For Each dirLine As String In dirlist

        Dim dirData As String = dirLine

        ' Parse date
        Dim lineDate As String = dirData.Substring(0, 17)
        Dim dateTime__1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(lineDate)
        dirData = dirData.Remove(0, 24)

        ' check if line is a directory
        Dim dir As String = dirData.Substring(0, 5)
        Dim isDirectory As Boolean = dir.Equals("<dir>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        dirData = dirData.Remove(0, 5)
        dirData = dirData.Remove(0, 10)

        ' get the filename
        If Not isDirectory Then
            Dim fileName As String = dirData

            'the actual filename
            Console.WriteLine("name= " & fileName)

        End If
    Next

    reader.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: Tried your code and still giving me the illegible chars. `ListDirectoryDetails` works the same as `ListDirectory` for retrieving the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the code seemed to work fine with accented Latin characters - it wasn't an encoding of Latin characters so much as it was the # hash/number symbol.

The answer to that came from [Gary Yang (Microsoft Online Community Support)](http://forums.asp.net/t/1476136.aspx?FtpWebRequest%20and%20permitted%20characters). The key was to use Uri.EscapeDataString(). His answer didn't work, but out of respect it is below:

> I suggest you try to encode the file path. Please refer to the following code:

```
string FTPFilePath = "ftp://myserverip.com/Beatles #1 Hits/Help document.mp3";
if ((FTPFilePath).IndexOf("#") > -1){
 targetUri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeDataString(FTPFilePath));
}
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
```

Here's my working version:

```
Dim ftpFilePath = "ftp://myserverip.com/Beatles #1 Hits/Help document.mp3"

Dim parsedUri = new Uri(ftpFilePath)
Dim scheme = parsedUri.Scheme
Dim host = parsedUri.Host
Dim port = parsedUri.Port
Dim pathThatMightHaveHashSigns = ftpFilePath.Replace(String.Format("{0}://{1}", scheme, host), String.Empty)

'Dim targetUri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeDataString(ftpFilePath))
' The above line would throw a UriFormatException "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

Dim targetUri = new UriBuilder(scheme, host, port, pathThatMightHaveHashSigns).Uri
Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(targetUri), FtpWebRequest)
```

... and for C#:

```
var ftpFilePath = "ftp://myserverip.com/Beatles #1 Hits/Help document.mp3";

var parsedUri = new Uri(ftpFilePath);
var scheme = parsedUri.Scheme;
var host = parsedUri.Host;
var port = parsedUri.Port;
var pathThatMightHaveHashSigns = ftpFilePath.Replace(String.Format("{0}://{1}", scheme, host), String.Empty);

//var targetUri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeDataString(ftpFilePath));
// The above line would throw a UriFormatException "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

var targetUri = new UriBuilder(scheme, host, port, pathThatMightHaveHashSigns).Uri;
targetUri.Dump();
```

Comment: Oh, also I realized I have 
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
set so maybe that means I don't have to specify string encodings?