# Ftp create a filename with utf-8 chars such as greek, german etc

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, ftp

I am trying to create a file to an ftp server with the following code (where I also tried with UseBinary option true and false)

```
string username = "name";
string password = "password";
string remotefolder = "ftp://ftp.myhost.gr/public_html/test/";
string remoteFileName = "δοκιμαστικό αρχείοüß-äCopy.txt";
string localFile = @"C:\test\δοκιμαστικό αρχείο - Copy.txt";
String ftpname = "ftp://ftp.myhost.gr/public_html/test" + @"/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(Program.remoteFileName);


FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpname);
request.Proxy = null;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);


request.UsePassive = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.UseBinary = true;
//request.UseBinary = false;

 byte[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(localFile);
 byte[] fileContents = new Byte[content.Length];

 Array.Copy(content, 0, fileContents, 0, content.Length);

 using (Stream uploadStream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
     int contentLength = fileContents.Length;
     uploadStream.Write(fileContents, 0, contentLength);
 }

 FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 Console.WriteLine(response.ExitMessage);
```

The problem is that file at my ftp server does not get the name 
I request which contains English, greek and german characters --> "δοκιμαστικό αρχείοüß-äCopy.txt

**1) What can I do with that?**

There is some improvement once I change my regional settings--> Current language for non-Unicode programs to Greek Language but I still miss the german chars.

**2) Why does a c# program depend on this setting? Is there a special methodology i should follow in order to avoid dependency from this setting?**

Encoding nightmares arose again :(

Comment: _"The problem is that file at my ftp server does not get the name I request"_ does the FTP protocol support Unicode? And what about your server software?

Comment: I think not. But since I can do it from cpanel and most interestingly from filezilla (with force utf-8 option) then I think I should be able to do it via C#..

Comment: What FTP-Server software are you using?

Comment: Well I do not own the server. The only thing that I know is that it is Linux OS

Comment: Did you try to change the encoding such as in this [answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369863/ftpwebrequest-filename-contains-german-umlaute-like-a-o

Comment: So what vocabulary should I use? I mean how should I know that an ä in filename needs to be replaced by an ae, in order to use it for other "special characters' too?

Comment: How are you going to access these FTP files? Via www?

Answer (score 10):

It is not enough for you just to encode your string as UTF8 and send it as filename to FTP server. In the past all FTP servers understood ASCII only and nowadays to maintain backward compatibility - even if they are Unicode aware - when they start they treat all filenemes as ASCII too.

To make it all work you (your program) must first check what your server is capable of. Servers send their features after client connects - in your case you must check for **FEAT UTF8**. If your server sends that - it means it understands UTF8. Nevertheless - even if it understands it - you must tell it explicitly that from now on you will send your filenames UTF8 encoded and now it is the stuff that your program lacks (as your server supports utf8 as you've stated).

Your client must send to FTP server the following **OPTS UTF8 ON**. After sending that you may use UTF8 or speak UTF8-ish (so to speak) to your sever.

Read here for details [Internationalization of the File Transfer Protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2640.txt)

Answer (score 4):

In your code change:

```
string localFile = @"C:\test\δοκιμαστικό αρχείο - Copy.txt";
String ftpname = "ftp://ftp.myhost.gr/public_html/test" + @"/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(Program.remoteFileName);

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpname);
```

To:

```
string remoteFileName = "δοκιμαστικό αρχείο - Copy.txt";
String ftpname = "ftp://ftp.myhost.gr/public_html/test" + @"/" + remoteFileName;

var escapedUriString = Uri.EscapeUriString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ftpname)));
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(escapedUriString);
```

This needs to be done because [EscapeUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s input parameter is escaped according to the RFC 2396 specification.

The [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) standard states:

> When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual data
> consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [UCS], the
> data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8
> character encoding [STD63]; then only those octets that do not
> correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be
> percent-encoded.

Hence the code change shown above will force this string to be inputted in the UTF-8 format.

With regards to:

> 2. Why does a c# program depend on this setting? Is there a special
>    methodology i should follow in order to avoid dependency from this
>    setting?

`Uri.EscapeUriString` needs input which follows the RFC 2396 specification, hence the need to pass it data in a format which it will understand.

Comment: this did not work but thank you for your answer. I will search it further. Up vote from me, but not sure that it is the solution

Comment: Just to double check, I assume that Program.remoteFileName and remoteFileName are the same?

Comment: Yes remoteFileName is exactly the same object as Program.remoteFileName

Comment: I've updated my answer. I was only partially escaping the string passed to WebRequest.Create. I've updated my answer to ensure that the whole of the string passed to WebRequest.Create is escaped.