# Why when downloading a file from my ftp server on the hard disk i see it 100???.jpg?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file-upload, ftp

First this is the file name original on my hard disk: שקל100.jpg
שקל is a word in hebrew
When i'm uploading the file to my ftp there are no problems with the upload but the file name on the ftp server look like:

[image: File on ftp server]

The file on the ftp server looks like with gibrish instead hebrew.
The problem is when i'm trying to download the file. The file name is 100???.jpg
And the FtpWebrequest dosen't know what is 100???.jpg

```
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fileurl);
```

In fileurl i see: ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/D/100???.jpg

The question is what can i do in this case ? Maybe to force the file name to be renaimed to some default temp file name ?

I guess the problem is that the ftp server ipage.com host dosen't know to read hebrew so after uploading it looks like gibrish.

Or maybe i need to upload it somehow with encoding the file name using hebrew ?
This is the method i'm using to upload files:

```
private void StringArrayUploadFiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                UploadedFiles = files;
                foreach (string fn in files)
                {                  
                    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                    f = e.Argument as FtpSettings;
                    MakeDir(f.TargetFolder);
                    string UploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", f.Host, f.TargetFolder == "" ? "" : f.TargetFolder + "/", Path.GetFileName(fn));
                    if (!UploadPath.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
                        UploadPath = "ftp://" + UploadPath;
                    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadPath);
                    request.UseBinary = true;
                    request.UsePassive = f.Passive;
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    request.Timeout = 300000;
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
                    long FileSize = new FileInfo(fn).Length;//f.SourceFile).Length;
                    string FileSizeDescription = GetFileSize(FileSize);
                    int ChunkSize = 4096, NumRetries = 0, MaxRetries = 50;
                    long SentBytes = 0;
                    byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
                    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            int BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                            while (BytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (bw.CancellationPending)
                                        return;

                                    requestStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead);

                                    SentBytes += BytesRead;

                                    string SummaryText = String.Format("Transferred {0} / {1}", GetFileSize(SentBytes), FileSizeDescription);
                                    bw.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)SentBytes / (decimal)FileSize) * 100), SummaryText);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                                    if (NumRetries++ < MaxRetries)
                                    {
                                        fs.Position -= BytesRead;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        throw new Exception(String.Format("Error occurred during upload, too many retries. \n{0}", ex.ToString()));
                                    }
                                }
                                BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));
                }
                //}
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Status)
                {
                    case WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure:
                        ConnectionError = "Error: Please check the ftp address";
                        break;
                    case WebExceptionStatus.Timeout:
                        ConnectionError = "Error: Timout Request";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I did a test now trying to upload one single file with hebrew in the name of the file.
In the variable files i see the file with the hebrew letters fine.
And the file uploaded without any exceptions or problems.

And this is how the file looks like on the ftp server after uploaded it with gibrish again:

[image: Uploaded test file]

What can i do about this situation ? Encoding before doing the upload in the upload method should solve it ? If so how can i do the encoding ?

Comment: Does your FTP server and OS support unicode names?

Comment: Darek my os yes i'm not sure about my ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

It might be as simple as changing your FTP server, or [configuring to support Unicode characters](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Character_Set), or switching to SFTP.

> If an RFC 2640 compliant client sends OPTS UTF-8 ON, it has to use UTF-8 regardless whether OPTS UTF-8 ON succeeds or not. RFC 2640 compliant servers must not make UTF-8 dependent on OPTS UTF-8 ON.

[Ftp create a filename with utf-8 chars such as greek, german etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727557/ftp-create-a-filename-with-utf-8-chars-such-as-greek-german-etc)

If that's not an option, than I'm afraid you will have to perform the file name encoding and decoding yourself in this case.

```
const string fileName = "100%ץצקרתﬤﬢ.jpg";
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fileName);
var doubleBytes = bytes.ToObservable().Buffer(2);

var asciiFileName = new StringBuilder();
doubleBytes.Subscribe(
    s =>
        asciiFileName.Append(s[1] == 0
            ? (s[0] == 37 ? "%25" : Convert.ToString((char) s[0]))
            : String.Format("%{0:X2}%{1:X2}", s[0], s[1]).PadLeft(2, '0')));
```

I am utterly lazy here relying on Reactive Extensions to buffer the data for me.

the value of asciiFileName will be

```
100%25%E5%05%E6%05%E7%05%E8%05%EA%05%24%FB%22%FB.jpg
```

Not the prettiest one, but it preserves the original characters. You might run into additional challenges with left- and right- aligned string so thread lightly ... :)

If you prefer not to use Rx, than this extension will do the trick:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<byte[]> ToBytePairs(this byte[] array)
    {
        var enumerator = array.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var bytePair = new byte[2];
            bytePair[0] = (byte)enumerator.Current;
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            bytePair[1] = (byte)enumerator.Current;
            yield return bytePair;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this gives you a start, but you have to write the reverse procedure yourself. :)

**UPDATE**

I took a Microsoft sample and confirmed that it works with the FileZilla server (mentioned before)

```
#region

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

#endregion

namespace FtpUnicodeClient
{
    public class FtpState
    {
        private readonly ManualResetEvent _wait;

        public FtpState()
        {
            OperationException = null;
            _wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public ManualResetEvent OperationComplete
        {
            get { return _wait; }
        }

        public FtpWebRequest Request { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public Exception OperationException { get; set; }

        public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class AsynchronousFtpUpLoader
    {
        // Command line arguments are two strings: 
        // 1. The url that is the name of the file being uploaded to the server. 
        // 2. The name of the file on the local machine. 
        // 
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a Uri instance with the specified URI string. 
            // If the URI is not correctly formed, the Uri constructor 
            // will throw an exception.

            var target = new Uri(args[0]);
            string fileName = args[1];
            var state = new FtpState();
            var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(target + fileName);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example uses anonymous logon. 
            // The request is anonymous by default; the credential does not have to be specified.  
            // The example specifies the credential only to 
            // control how actions are logged on the server.

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("demo", "demo");

            // Store the request in the object that we pass into the 
            // asynchronous operations.
            state.Request = request;
            state.FileName = fileName;

            // Get the event to wait on.
            ManualResetEvent waitObject = state.OperationComplete;

            // Asynchronously get the stream for the file contents.
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(EndGetStreamCallback, state);

            // Block the current thread until all operations are complete.
            waitObject.WaitOne();

            // The operations either completed or threw an exception. 
            if (state.OperationException != null)
            {
                throw state.OperationException;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The operation completed - {0}", state.StatusDescription);
        }

        private static void EndGetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var state = (FtpState) ar.AsyncState;

            // End the asynchronous call to get the request stream. 
            try
            {
                Stream requestStream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
                // Copy the file contents to the request stream. 
                const int bufferLength = 2048;
                var buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                int count = 0;
                int readBytes;
                FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(state.FileName);
                do
                {
                    readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    count += readBytes;
                } while (readBytes != 0);
                Console.WriteLine("Writing {0} bytes to the stream.", count);
                // IMPORTANT: Close the request stream before sending the request.
                requestStream.Close();
                // Asynchronously get the response to the upload request.
                state.Request.BeginGetResponse(EndGetResponseCallback, state);
            }
                // Return exceptions to the main application thread. 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not get the request stream.");
                state.OperationException = e;
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
            }
        }

        // The EndGetResponseCallback method   
        // completes a call to BeginGetResponse. 
        private static void EndGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var state = (FtpState) ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                var response = (FtpWebResponse) state.Request.EndGetResponse(ar);
                response.Close();
                state.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
                // Signal the main application thread that  
                // the operation is complete.
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
            }
                // Return exceptions to the main application thread. 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error getting response.");
                state.OperationException = e;
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check your FTP log files. It seems that the FtpWebRequest client already sends the required commands:

```
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - (not logged in) (::1)> Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - (not logged in) (::1)> USER demo
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - (not logged in) (::1)> 331 Password required for demo
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - (not logged in) (::1)> PASS ****
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> 230 Logged on
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> OPTS utf8 on
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> 202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command.
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> PWD
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> TYPE I
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> 200 Type set to I
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> EPSV
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||7800|)
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> STOR 100ץצקרתﬤﬢ.txt
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> 150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/100ץצקרתﬤﬢ.txt"
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> 226 Successfully transferred "/100ץצקרתﬤﬢ.txt"
(000005)12/26/2014 15:17:15 PM - demo (::1)> disconnected.
```