# FTP, GetRequestStream(), Error 550 when there's non English characters

Tags: c#

I’m setting up a new FTP server, and in my `uploadfile` function: `FTPWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` throws an exception:

> Error 550 File Unavailable

When the filename contains non English characters such as Arabic characters.

I've tried to upload files that only contain English characters, it works.

Can anyone help me with this?

this is a short version of the code i'm using:

```cs
System.Net.FtpWebRequest UploadFTPRequest = null;
string URI = Hostname + target;

UploadFTPRequest = GetRequest((URI));

UploadFTPRequest.Method = 
System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
UploadFTPRequest.UseBinary = true;

UploadFTPRequest.ContentLength = fi.Length;
UploadFileInfo = fi;

const int BufferSize = 2048;
byte[] content = new byte[BufferSize - 1 + 1];
int dataRead;

using (UploadFileStream = fi.OpenRead())
{
    try
    {
        //Exception error 550
        UploadStream = UploadFTPRequest.GetRequestStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727557/ftp-create-a-filename-with-utf-8-chars-such-as-greek-german-etc

Comment: `var resourceURI = new UriBuilder(URI).ToString(); UploadFTPRequest = GetRequest(resourceURI);`. -- `byte[] content = new byte[BufferSize - 1 + 1];`? Your FTP Upload proc is all over the place. BTW, are you sure you don't need authentication?